# findOneAndUpdate doesn't make update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack, insert-update

I am using mongoose with mean stack, I want to add a column `age` to my data saved in the database which contains a value of email 'a@a.a'

```
var MyModel = db.model('MyModel', userSchema);
var query =  {'email' : 'a@a.a' };
MyModel.findOneAndUpdate(query,{ 'age': '20' } , {upsert:true},function(err, doc){
if (err) return res.send(500, { error: err });
//return res.send("succesfully saved");
console.log('check');
});
```

but when I run in the mongo shell db.users.find({"email" : "a@a.a" }) I can't see the column added

Comment: How about `db.mymodels.find({"email" : "a@a.a" })`?

Comment: `var MyModel = db.mymodels.find({"email" : "a@a.a" })
                          ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'find' of undefined`

Comment: Sorry, I meant in the shell.  A model's collection name is the lower-cased, pluralized version of the model name by default.  'MyModel' => 'mymodels'

Comment: in the shell, it works OK, but when i run node server, i have always the same mistake

Answer (score 0):

I don't need the variable `MyModel`, :

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(query,{ age: 'age1' } , {upsert:true},function(err, doc){
```